# Pass too much params from UI to UseCase Android Clean Architecture

Tags: android, design-patterns, use-case, clean-architecture

I am applying Clean Architecture, but actually still have many questions about it.

Suppose, my API `@POST fun createJob(@Body request: JobRequest)`. And the params are provided from UI. So,

1. In `data`: I have created a `JobRequest` like below:

```kotlin
data class JobRequest(
    @Expose @SerializedName("p1") val p1: String?,
...
    @Expose @SerializedName("p7") val p7: String?
)
```

2. In `domain`:
   I create a `CreateJobUseCase` like below:

```kotlin
class CreateJobUseCase(private val userRepository: UserRepository) :
    BaseUseCase<CreateJobUseCase.Input, Job>() {

    override suspend fun execute(input: Input): Job {
        return userRepository.createJob(input.p1, ...input.p7)
    }

    data class Input(
       val p1: String,
       ....
       val p7: String,
   ) : BaseInput()
}
```

2. In `presentation`: I will call from `ViewModel` like:

```kotlin
   createJobUseCase.execute(CreateJobUseCase.Input(p1, p2...p7)) {
     //handle output
   }
```

My question is:

In `domain`, should my `UserRepository` interface like A or B?

```kotlin
A: suspend fun createJob(input: CreateJobUseCase.Input) : Job

or

B: suspend fun createJob(p1: String,... p7: String) : Job
```

In many projects, I saw them use `B`, it seems the repository function is cleared. But, I think `A` still ok, because it's still flow the dependency rule, and `CreateJobUseCase.Input` already contains what we need for `createJob` function. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what logic are you going to put inside your function.
Overall, I think you should choose whatever variant you like better and what fits your needs beter.

Also, if you're going to use same type variables I can propose another option `C)`. Maybe ***vararg*** would fit your needs even better? At least function's constructor would be shorter and cleaner. E.g.:

```
suspend fun createJob(vararg p: String) {
    for (item in p) {
        println(item)
    }
}
```

And then you could call your function like this:

```
createJob("1", "2", "3")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the C you give is a special of my case. I want to hear more explanation about the right way, because I am not sure about my solutions.

Comment: For example, if you're planning on covering this UseCase with Unit tests, you should think about how would you want to pass data into `createJob` function. How would you find it to be more convenient for you... 
Let's say you would have 5 different tests. Would it be more convenient for you to to pass A `CreateJobUseCase.Input` to the `createJob` function or would it be more convinient to pass B `p1: String,... p7: String` to the `createJob` function or it would be more convinient to pass C `vararg p: String` to the `createJob` function. 
Don't worry about the right way. Suit your own needs.